# how to get source file in HttpRequest for uploading file

Tags: java, web-services, rest, file-upload, httprequest

I have a problem with upload file in REST web service using java. I don't know how to get the source file.
  The curl command is like that

curl --upload-file /home/student1/text1.txt http://localhost:20260/project/resources/user1/sub-folder/text1.txt

My question is anyone know how to get the source file url "/home/student1/text1.txt" in REST web service @PUT method?Or any other way to get it?

thanks

Comment: That file is on the client computer, therefore you can't access it from the server, or am I missing something?

Comment: But inorder to upload file i need to know the URL , am i right? BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/student1/text1.txt");  So that I can read it. Coz I am new to web service. And I am confuse Server side and Client side

Comment: A file comes across an HTTP request as part of a multipart form.  You should dedicate some time to learning how HTTP works (GET, POST, DELETE requests and responses).  In today's world, that's very valuable

Comment: See my comment below, this curl example uses PUT as opposed to multipart/form-data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that curl uses mltipart/form-data as content type for the upload.
The filename would be part of the Content-Disposition header of the first MIME part.

Comment: The `--upload-file` option to curl tells it to send the contents of the file as the body of an HTTP PUT request as opposed multipart/form-data formatting.

Comment: thanks for the correction. In this case, there is no standard mechanism to transmit the original file name

Comment: hi laz, do u know how to get the contents of the file from PUT request. thanks

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer was selected as it is not correct. The example curl command does not use multipart/form-data. You should probably follow Milimetric's advice above and familiarize yourself with HTTP.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not terribly familiar with JAX-RS but I think the following code does what you are looking for:

```
package org.restlet.example;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;

@Path("project/resources/{user}/{directory}/{filename}")
public class JaxRsResource {
    private static final int BLOCK_SIZE = 8192;
    private static final Map<String, MediaType> MEDIA_TYPE_MAP = new HashMap<String, MediaType>();

    @Context
    private UriInfo uriInfo;

    @Context
    private HttpHeaders httpHeaders;

    @PathParam("user")
    private String user;

    @PathParam("directory")
    private String directory;

    @PathParam("filename")
    private String filename;

    @QueryParam("name")
    private String name;

    @QueryParam("type")
    private String type;

    static {
        MEDIA_TYPE_MAP.put("txt", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE);
        MEDIA_TYPE_MAP.put("gif", MediaType.valueOf("image/gif"));
        MEDIA_TYPE_MAP.put("jpg", MediaType.valueOf("image/jpeg"));
        MEDIA_TYPE_MAP.put("png", MediaType.valueOf("image/png"));
        MEDIA_TYPE_MAP.put("zip", MediaType.valueOf("application/zip"));
    }

    public JaxRsResource() {
    }

    @PUT
    @Consumes({"text/plain", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif", "application/zip"})
    public Response upload(final byte[] contents) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        FileOutputStream output = null;
        try {
            final File directories = new File(user, directory);
            directories.mkdirs();
            final File file = new File(directories, filename);
            output = new FileOutputStream(file);
            output.write(contents);
        } finally {
            if (output != null) {
                output.flush();
                output.close();
            }
        }
        return Response.created(uriInfo.getAbsolutePath()).build();
    }

    @GET
    @Produces({"text/plain", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif", "application/zip"})
    public Response output() throws IOException {
        final String extension = filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
        final ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        InputStream input = null;
        try {
            input = new FileInputStream(new File(new File(user, directory), filename));
            final byte[] buffer = new byte[BLOCK_SIZE];
            int read = 0;
            while ((read = input.read(buffer)) > -1) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
        } finally {
            if (input != null) {
                input.close();
            }
        }
        final byte[] byteArray = output.toByteArray();
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        return Response.ok(byteArray, MEDIA_TYPE_MAP.get(extension)).build();
    }

}
```

I haven't verified that it is safe against trying to put `..` for either `user` or `directory` so it might require input sanitation. Also, the errors and exceptions needs to be handled better.

I tested this out with curl and it creates the file on the server file system containing the contents of the file passed via `--upload-file` which can then be retrieved by issuing a GET to the same resource. I did have to add the Content-Type header to the curl request to get it working though:

```
curl -v -T test.txt -H "Content-Type: text/plain" http://localhost:8182/project/resources/user1/sub-folder/test.txt
```

I tested this out using [Restlet's](http://www.restlet.org/) implementation of [JAX-RS](http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.0/13-restlet/28-restlet/57-restlet.html).

This new version handles your additional requirement of supporting the query parameters you mentioned in the other comment. I refactored it to use properties instead of method arguments, since the argument lists were growing unwieldy. I learned that it is thread safe to do so from the JAX-RS spec. Also, I modified the code to support plain text and binary files, though I haven't tried it with different file encodings. Since the method is expecting a byte array input I'm hoping that the JAX-RS framework does the right thing and can tell which encoding to use if one is provided in the request's Content-Type header.

Comment: hi laz,there is error in uploading pictures and zip file.Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: You probably need to correct the Content-Type. The example I provided only works for Content-Type text/plain. Also, using Writer and Reader objects won't work for binary data such as images or zip files. You would need to use OutputStream and InputStream objects.

Comment: hi laz, i want to get the parameter of value "name" and "type" in  url : http://localhost:8080/project/resources/user/sub-folder?name=john&type=shared  Do you know how can I get both name and type's value? I used query param ,but i only get name's value.  thanks

Comment: hi laz, Do you know how to hide the command. Now when we upload file we need to write like : curl -v -T /home/student1/file.jpg http://localhost:8080/project/resources/user/file.jpg . I want to know can I upload without knowing the upload path like : curl -v http://localhost:8080/project/resources/user/file.jpg . Do you know how to hide the source file?

Comment: I'm not sure that is possible. The -T tells curl what data to send. You can shorten the command like this though `curl -v -T /home/student1/file.jpg http://localhost:8080/project/resources/user/sub-folder/` leaving the file name off of the target URL and curl will use the file name passed via -T. curl doesn't seem to like that with the query parameters added though, so if you need those you are stuck providing the file name.